# CSS Grid: Create a new row when child content overflows column width

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a two column layout based on CSS Grid. When the second column's content exceeds `1fr` I'd like a new row created. As it stands, the content simply overflows the column.

A requirement of this layout is the items in the `right-menu` column are in a single row. I'm achieving this with:

```
.right-menu {
  ...
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
  ...
}
```

If I remove the `grid-auto-flow` property, the overflow stops. But, the items are now stacked into multiple rows, which is not what I want.

I've also tried changing `.right-menu` to

```
.right-menu {
  display: 'inline-flex';
}
```

But, it's the same result as before. The content overflows the column.  Is there a way to do this without Javascript? Media queries are out since this is content based, not viewport width.

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1.0rem;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 1.0rem 0 0 1.0rem;
}

.menu-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(600px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-row-gap: 1.0rem;
}

.left-menu {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.right-menu {
  display: grid;
  background-color: white;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(65px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: column dense; 
  grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 0.75rem;
}

.right-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 65px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="menu-grid">
        <div class="left-menu">Left</div>
            <div class="right-menu">
                <div class="right-item">Item: 1</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 2</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 3</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 4</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 5</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 6</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 7</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 8</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 9</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 10</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 11</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 12</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 13</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want a new row to be added, better use `flex` instead of `grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have better luck with flexbox

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1.0rem;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 1.0rem 0 0 1.0rem;
}

.menu-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1.0rem;
}
.menu-grid > * {
  flex: 600px;
}
.left-menu {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.right-menu {
  display: grid;
  background-color: white;
  grid-auto-columns: 65px;
  grid-auto-flow: column; 
  grid-row-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 0.75rem;
}

.right-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 65px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="menu-grid">
        <div class="left-menu">Left</div>
            <div class="right-menu">
                <div class="right-item">Item: 1</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 2</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 3</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 4</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 5</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 6</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 7</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 8</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 9</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 10</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 11</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 12</div>
                <div class="right-item">Item: 13</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```